# Convert image URL into File instance

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have array of image data, and trying to convert it into array of `File`s

```
const images = [
  { img: "http://localhost/images/1.jpg", name: "1.png", mime_type: "image/jpeg" },
  { img: "http://localhost/images/2.jpg", name: "2.png", mime_type: "image/jpeg" },
]
const res: File[] = images.map(function (item) {
  return new File([item.img], item.name, { type: item.mime_type })
})
```

This does not work :( As I understand it, the converted image in base24 should be passed to the file constructor? How can I do that?

UPD:
I have a VUE component to work with images. The input component has a property of type Array. How to create an Array based on the data returned by database. Returns from the database: image link, name and type.

UPD2 answer:

```
let PhotosAsFile: File[] = []
const _photos = [
  { url: "http://localhost:8080/images/1.jpeg", name: "name1", mime_type: "image/jpeg" },
  { url: "http://localhost:8080/images/2.jpeg", name: "name2", mime_type: "image/jpeg" },
  { url: "http://localhost:8080/images/3.jpeg", name: "name3", mime_type: "image/jpeg" },
]

const data: Promise<File>[] = _photos.map(async function (item): Promise<File> {
  const myBlob: Blob = await getBlobFromUrl(item.url)
  const extensionsFile: RegExpMatchArray | null | undefined = item.url?.match(/\.([^.]+)$/)

  return new File([myBlob], extensionsFile && item.name ? item.name + "." + extensionsFile[1] : "image.jpeg", {
    type: item.mime_type ?? "image/jpeg",
  })
})

Promise.all(data).then((values: File[]): void => {
  PhotosAsFile = values
})

const getBlobFromUrl = (url): Promise<Blob> => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject): void => {
    const request: XMLHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest()
    request.open("GET", url, true)
    request.responseType = "blob"
    request.onload = () => {
      resolve(request.response)
    }
    request.onerror = reject
    request.send()
  })
}
```

Comment: What is not working here?

Comment: Just a guess: did you end up with some files, that contained the names of the jpeg files.

Comment: Down vote for now, as you told us "something went wrong, some where". Show us what happened when you ran the program. Tell us what you expected to happen.

Comment: Do you need to download and store the image as `File` object?

Comment: Updated the question, good people

Comment: I answered as I

Comment: Is the modified question title correct?

Answer (score 0):

To create `File` (i'm not sure why you'd ever need that), you need to pass in the binary data

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/File

> `new File(bits, name, options?)`
> **bits**
> An iterable object such as an Array, having ArrayBuffers, TypedArrays, DataViews, Blobs, strings, or a mix of any of such elements, that will be put inside the File. Note that strings here are encoded as UTF-8, unlike the usual JavaScript UTF-16 strings.

That's a file in memory. You can't read it from the disk. You can't write it to the disk. You can set it as value of  and send as FormData I guess.

Comment: I have a VUE component to work with images. The input component has a property of type Array. How to create an Array based on the data returned by database. Returns from the database: image link, name and type.

Comment: @Goryyn to show image all you need is url to put into `<img :src="url">`. `<img v-for="img of images" :src="img.img">` is all you need

Comment: I understand that this is possible, but it does not suit me. I can't create a File() based on an image link? Somehow convert the image to base64...which the new File() constructor requires?

Comment: I answered as I

Comment: @Goryyn your answer shold be an "answer" same as mine and not a part of question

Answer (score -1):

Answer

```
let PhotosAsFile: File[] = []
const _photos = [
  { url: "http://localhost:8080/images/1.jpeg", name: "name1", mime_type: "image/jpeg" },
  { url: "http://localhost:8080/images/2.jpeg", name: "name2", mime_type: "image/jpeg" },
  { url: "http://localhost:8080/images/3.jpeg", name: "name3", mime_type: "image/jpeg" },
]

const data: Promise<File>[] = _photos.map(async function (item): Promise<File> {
  const myBlob: Blob = await getBlobFromUrl(item.url)
  const extensionsFile: RegExpMatchArray | null | undefined = item.url?.match(/\.([^.]+)$/)

  return new File([myBlob], extensionsFile && item.name ? item.name + "." + extensionsFile[1] : "image.jpeg", {
    type: item.mime_type ?? "image/jpeg",
  })
})

Promise.all(data).then((values: File[]): void => {
  PhotosAsFile = values
})

const getBlobFromUrl = (url): Promise<Blob> => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject): void => {
    const request: XMLHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest()
    request.open("GET", url, true)
    request.responseType = "blob"
    request.onload = () => {
      resolve(request.response)
    }
    request.onerror = reject
    request.send()
  })
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).